# How do I update my object value using these "RandNumber()" function in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    // random number generator
        int RandNumber() {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.nextInt(100);
          }
    
    // this is my list of object
    
        var question = [
            {
              'question': 'question 1',
              'answer': [
                {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'A'},
                {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'B'},
                {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'C'},
                {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'D'},
              ],
            },
          ];
}
```

this is showing error when calling **RandNumber()** function.

could you like to help me, please?

Comment: _What_ error? Give a [mre].

Comment: Also, I know this is just an example but you should really not create a new `Random` object for each number you want to generate. Instead, create a global variable containing a `Random` instance and reuse that. :)

Comment: @MdjahidulAlamSagar Atleast post your full code. At present, there is no tangible evidence to prove anything.

Comment: this is my real code, if i could implement random number then i would go for original one. 
writing this way also gives errors
`var randomGenerator = Random();
  var question = [
    {
      'question': 'question 1',
      'answer': [
        {'value': randomGenerator.nextInt(100), 'data': 'A'},
      ],
    },
  ];`
error is 
**The instance member 'randomGenerator' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondartimplicit_this_reference_in_initializer**

Comment: @MdjahidulAlamSagar Based on the error it sounds like you have this inside a class definition? Why is this not part of your code example in your question?

Comment: this is part of my code. would you like to give a glimpse in ideone editor? here is the link 
[link](https://ideone.com/lHWtSA)

Comment: @MdjahidulAlamSagar Context is really important in most issues. This is why it is important to always create a minimal reproducible example and post that as jonrsharpe also suggests. In this case, it was obvious for us what the problem was if you have just posted the class definition and the full error message.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. i'll try my best to improve myself . thank you very much :) .

Comment: Please follow the capitalization and camel/snake case conventions of Dart/Flutter identifiers.  These are described at the "Effective Dart" style guide in dart.dev

Answer (score 2):

You can't put your `RandNumber` function inside of your Widget class which makes it an `instance variable` which can't be used in initializers.

Move it outside and then you can use it.

```
int RandNumber() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(100);
}

class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    var question = [
        {
            'question': 'question 1',
            'answer': [
                {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'A'},
                {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'B'},
                {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'C'},
                {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'D'},
            ],
        },
    ];

    // Rest of your Widget code
```

Comment: Wonderfully short and precise :D

Answer (score 2):

Based on your error message in your comments it sounds like your code are something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  // random number generator
  int RandNumber() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(100);
  }

  // this is my list of object
  var question = [
    {
      'question': 'question 1',
      'answer': [
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'A'},
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'B'},
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'C'},
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'D'},
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```

This will give the error:

```
The instance member 'RandNumber' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

The reason for this is that your `RandNumber()` method requires the object to be created before you can call the method (since the method is part of your object).

Since `RandNumber()` does not really require anything from the `class` you can either move the method outside the class definition as Nisanth Reddy suggests. Or change the method to static since it will then exists directly on the class level:

```
class MyClass {
  // random number generator
  static int RandNumber() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(100);
  }

  // this is my list of object
  var question = [
    {
      'question': 'question 1',
      'answer': [
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'A'},
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'B'},
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'C'},
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'D'},
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```

Also, never create `Random` objects every time you need a random number. You should do this instead:

```
class MyClass {
  static final Random _random = Random();
  
  // random number generator
  static int RandNumber() => _random.nextInt(100)

  // this is my list of object
  var question = [
    {
      'question': 'question 1',
      'answer': [
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'A'},
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'B'},
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'C'},
        {'value': RandNumber(), 'data': 'D'},
      ],
    },
  ];
}
```

The reason is a little technical but it is about a problematic behavior where you get random numbers of a really bad quality. I have written the details in this issue: https://github.com/Daegalus/dart-uuid/issues/59

Comment: Wonderfully Detailed :D

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation. it also works well. i have got it .  :)